# Is there a way to drop in a stylesheet to get a Material theme or similar for all form elements on the page?

Tags: html, css, material-design

Is there a way to drop in a stylesheet that updates the form elements to material theme?

I'm using a plain HTML page and want the theme to fill in the width and heights of the form elements I have on the page.

I can assign class names to the elements to style them or if the stylesheet would apply to existing elements that would work as well.

Comment: Have you had a look at this : https://materializecss.com/radio-buttons.html ?

Comment: @Clafou That's pretty neat

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the Material Design classes after you include the asset files in your project header and footer.

### CDN:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
```

## NPM:

```
npm install @material/form-field
```

---

**Button Example:**
To style the button (submit for example), you add class as following, where `foo-button` will be your custom CSS to overwrite:

```
<button class="mdc-button foo-button">Button</button>
```

**Form Example**: 
To style the form you can follow the [Form Fields](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/form-fields/) instruction.

```
<div class="mdc-form-field">
  <div class="mdc-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox" class="mdc-checkbox__native-control"/>
    <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="my-checkbox">This is my checkbox</label>
</div>
```

The JS part to handle error and validation is a little bit tricky, but if you use the console to manage the handlers etc, you should be able to manage.